# Can anyone identify this flowering vine?

Tags: identification

Found this vine growing in southeast Florida and thought it was fantastic.  It’s a climbing vine with 4 inch wide flowers.  The vine was at least 12 ft wide and the height of the fence.[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is *Aristolochia*, probably *A. littoralis*, an evergreen climbing plant. It does not tolerate cold conditions, but will grow well in a sheltered position in places where the temperature does not fall below 10-15deg. C. Further information here https://www.rhs.org.uk/Plants/1580/Aristolochia-littoralis/Details